# Does TM $M$ exist, when $L_{\leq3} \subset L(M) \subset L_{\leq4}$

Tags: turing-machines

and
$L_{\leq k} = \{\langle M \rangle : |L(M)|\leq k\}$

The solution that I saw is:

Proof by contradiction, assume such $M$ exists.

So reduction $f$ from $\overline{HP}$ to $L(M)$,
when $\overline{HP}=\{(\langle M\rangle,x ) | M $ doesn't halt on $ x\}$

$f(\langle M'\rangle,x ) = \langle M_x\rangle$

When $M_x$ on input $w$ implemented in the following way:

1. execute $M'$ on $x$
2. accept if M' halt

I can't understand the validity of it, I mean why

$M_x \in L(M) \Leftrightarrow (\langle M'\rangle,x )\in \overline{HP}$

is true?

The next step quite simple, if $M$ exists then $L(M)\in RE$ and based on the reduction it's mean that $\overline{HP}\in RE$, contradiction.

Maybe I found wrong solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the solution you just need to accept any 3 elements of your choice in $M_x$. Now, $M_x$ will look something like that:

1. If $w$ (the input) is $0,1$ or $00$, accept .
2. Otherwise, emulate $M$ on $x$.
3. Accept if $M$ halted.

Now, you are guaranteed to have exactly 3 elements in $L(M_x)$ if $M$ doesnt halt on $x$, and otherwise $L(M_x)=\Sigma^*$.

You can now continue with the proof as you have written.

Comment: Thank you man!!